# DATAStack library in existing app with working core-data

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data

I have an application in which I already have working core-data and persistent storage functionality. I'd like use [DATAStack](https://github.com/3lvis/DATAStack) in this app, but I can't get it to work.

Without DATAStack I had al these standard core-data `lazy var`s in my `AppDelegate`. In my `ViewController` I retrieved the `managedObjectContext` like this: `let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext`. Passed the `moc` variable to the function that would take care of the storing and called `moc.save()` somewhere down the line. I know that this works, because I also retrieve and show the stored entries on the screen, which also works after completely closing the app. And I inspect the sqlite database with a sqlite database viewer (SQLPro for SQLite Read-Only).

Now with DATAStack I added a new line in my `AppDelegate`: `lazy var dataStack: DATAStack = DATAStack(modelName: "Database")`. The name of my database model is indeed `Database.xcdatamodeld` so the initialisation should be right. In my `ViewController` I replaced the `var moc = ...` described above with `let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).dataStack.mainContext`. Again this `moc` variable gets passed around and I call `moc.save()` somewhere down the line, but now it doesn't store anything.. As I described, the only thing that has changed is where the managed object context comes from.

I must be missing something with this library, but I have no clue what I'm missing.

I've also looked at a [Sync example](https://github.com/3lvis/SyncAppNetDemo) ([Sync](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Sync) uses DATAStack), but the `dataStack` object is retrieved in a whole different way there.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you shouldn't use the `mainContext` to save, but always a new background context. So the only way to get the right moc is like this:

```
dataStack.performInNewBackgroundContext() { moc in
    //Do things with moc and call moc.save() somewhere
}
```